My code will not work unless I restart my kernel
So I am looking to create a mini GUI, where I need to configure certain vales. The first time I ran this tool it worked, however, when I run it again without a fresh kernel ran values are stuck at their default values. I think it could be a memory leak issue, but I am not sure how to check.
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Mon Aug 26 08:55:59 2024

@author: khourym
"""

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

# Function to create a top-level dropdown GUI and return dictionary on submit
def create_dropdowns(options, root):
    # This dictionary will hold the labels as keys and dropdown values as values
    result = {}

    def validate_float_input(char, text):
        """ Validate the input for the float entry. """
        print(char)
        if (
            all(char in "0123456789.-" for char in text) and  # all characters are valid
            "-" not in text[1:] and # "-" is the first character or not present
            text.count(".") <= 1): # only 0 or 1 periods
                return True
        else:
            return False

    def on_submit():
        # Update the result dictionary with the current dropdown selections
        for option, var in variables.items():
            print(var.get())
            
            result[option] = var.get()  # Get the current value of the dropdown

        # Get the value of the float entry
        sv_value = float_entry_var.get()

        top.destroy()  # Close the top-level window

        return result, sv_value

    # Create a top-level window
    top = tk.Toplevel(root, background="cyan")
    top.title("Top-Level Dropdown GUI")

    # Create a frame to hold all dropdowns
    infoFrame = tk.Frame(top,background="cyan")
    infoFrame.pack()
    cTile = tk.Label(infoFrame, text="Please configure the Control Logic states in\n voltage with the VIH values and enter the nominal \nvoltage for the supply voltage(VCC) all in volts",background="cyan")
    cTile.pack(expand=False, fill='both')
    frame = tk.Frame(top, background="cyan")
    frame.pack()

    # Create a dictionary to hold variables associated with dropdown values
    variables = {}
    
    # Iterate over the array of strings and create a label and dropdown for each
    for option in options:
        # Create a label for the string
        

        dropdown_label = tk.Label(frame, text="Enter the value for the control logic " + option, background="cyan") 
        dropdown_label.pack(anchor="w") # Create a variable to hold the selected value for each option 
        var = tk.StringVar(value="X") # default value is "X" 
        
        
        float_entry = tk.Entry(frame, textvariable=var) 
        float_entry.pack(anchor="w") # Store the variable in the dictionary with the option label as the key 
        variables[option] = var # Create a label and entry box for the float value 

    # Create a label and entry box for the float value
    float_label = tk.Label(frame, text="Enter The supply voltage VIH value", background="cyan")
    float_label.pack(anchor="w")

    float_entry_var = tk.StringVar(value="5.0")  # default value is "0.0"

    # Register the validation function
    vcmd = (root.register(validate_float_input), "%S", "%P")
    float_entry = tk.Entry(frame, textvariable=float_entry_var, validate="key", validatecommand=vcmd)
    float_entry.pack(anchor="w")

    # Create a submit button
    submit_button = tk.Button(top, text="Submit", command=on_submit, background="skyblue")
    submit_button.pack(pady=10)

    # Start the Tkinter main loop
    root.wait_window(top)

    # Return the result dictionary with the label-value pairs and the float value
    return result, float(float_entry_var.get())

    
if __name__ == "__main__": 

    # Example usage
    options_array = ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"]
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()  # Hide the root window, only show the top-level window
    selected_values = create_dropdowns(options_array,root)
    print(selected_values)  # This will print the dictionary after you close the top-level GUI'''

with a fresh kernel: ({'Option 1': '4', 'Option 2': '4', 'Option 3': '7'}, 5.5)
not a fresh kernel: ({'Option 1': 'X', 'Option 2': 'X', 'Option 3': 'X'}, 5.0)
I am running this through spyder and the "restart kernel" is opening a new console through the app which in turn restarts kernel.

You can check by investigating the problem yourself first. Please provide a minimal reproducible example and don't include unnecessary code that you commented out. You can create a minimal reproducible example by taking pieces of code repeatedly away. At some point it might be obvious what causes the problem, otherwise it makes sense to ask a question here. Creating a minimal reproducible example also helps you to find similar questions and answers online.

You might get this to work by explicitly giving a parent for your StringVars (and any other Tkinter Var types), just as you give a parent for all of your widgets.  A Var with no parent becomes a child of the originally-created root window; if that window no longer exists, then the Var simply won't work.
